# Dockerfile RUN merge pip commands

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

I had an old dockerfile which looks like this

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ENV VISUAL=vim
ENV EDITOR=$VISUAL
ENV TERM=xterm
ENV TERMINFO=/etc/terminfo
ENV PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
RUN apt-get --yes update && apt-get --yes upgrade && apt-get --yes install python \
    python-dev \
    python-pip
<...lots of other apt-get install...>
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
<...other staffs>
```

It worked well, but I want to reduce image size by reducing layers. So I merged the last 2 lines

```
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
 pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But the build fails...

```
Step 15/45 : RUN pip install --upgrade pip &&  pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in b96971e60263
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/d7/90f34cb0d83a6c5631cf71dfe64cc1054598c843a92b400e55675cc2ac37/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.1
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Successfully installed pip-18.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

What did I miss when I merged those 2 lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hypothesis: In `pip install --upgrade pip`, the `pip` command run is `/usr/bin/pip`, and when it upgrades `pip`, it creates a new `pip` executable at `/usr/local/bin/pip`.  This new executable is what `pip install -r requirements.txt` is supposed to run, but when you put them in one `RUN` command and thus run them in a single shell instance, the shell's caching of command locations kicks in, and thus the second `pip` in `pip ... && pip ...` ends up being run from the same location as the first, which fails due to changes in pip's internals between the old and new version.  You can force the shell to uncache `pip`'s location by inserting `hash -d pip` in the middle of the single `RUN` command:

```
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
 hash -d pip && \
 pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: wow I've never thought of that. I tried `hash -d` but it says `/bin/sh: 1: hash: Illegal option -d`. If I remove `-d`, it works perfectly.